# Writing a package function that uses a dbplyr call to tbl()

Tags: r, odbc, dbplyr

I have a simple function that should fetch a table using a `DBI::dbConnect()` connection.  I am having trouble with the call to `tbl()` that works fine in an interactive session.

My function:

```
a2_db_read <- function(con, tbl_name, schema = "dbo"){
  if(schema == "dbo"){
    dplyr::tbl(con, tbl_name)
  }
  else{
    dplyr::tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema(schema, tbl_name))
  }
}
```

If I make the call `dplyr::tbl()` I get:

```
Error in UseMethod("tbl") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl' applied to an object of class "Microsoft SQL Server"
```

If I make the call `dbplyr::tbl()` I get:

```
a2_db_read(a2_con_uat, "AVL Data")
Error: 'tbl' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dbplyr'
```

How can I get that call to succeed in a function?  My package Imports is:

```
Imports: 
    DBI,
    dbplyr,
    dplyr,
    ggplot2,
    odbc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with `dplyr::tbl()`, the correct usage.

The problem was that my connection was stored as an object in a package when in fact the connection needs to be made every time I restart R.

On a fresh R environment, the stored stale connection caused the error:

> Error in UseMethod("tbl") :
> no applicable method for 'tbl' applied to an object of class "Microsoft SQL Server"

When I regenerated the connection, it worked.